# Increase text size in mars 4.5?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

Im using the MIPs Mars 4.5 and Im trying to find out how to increase the size of text such as the menu bar etc.. Not the editor but the program itself.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While there's no way within Mars to explicitly set the scaling, if you have a high dpi display and have everything in Windows scaled up, Windows' built-in compatibility can fix this.

The `runMARS.bat` calls `javaw.exe -jar Mars4_5.jar`

Assuming you've got java in your PATH...

1. **Navigate** to `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`
2. Right click on `javaw.exe`, -> **`Properties`**
3. In the `Compatibility` tab, **check** `Override high DPI scaling behavior`
4. **Select** `System` for `Scaling performed by`

Now, running Mars with **`runMARS.bat`** will start it with proper scaling.

If java isn't in your path, do the above steps for whichever executable `Mars4_5.jar` is using. If you're not sure, the `which javaw` command might come in handy.

Also, Java9 [properly supports](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/263) hidpi screens, so this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

open mars,

1.click on **settings** -> **editor...**

2.select the font-size that you want

3.click on apply